# Encoding Charset:UTF8 Problem in HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, json, encoding, utf-8, httpwebrequest

```
  var path = "/test";

            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequestContent = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Domain + path);
            httpWebRequestContent.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
            httpWebRequestContent.Accept = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
            httpWebRequestContent.PreAuthenticate = true;
            httpWebRequestContent.Headers.Add("token", Token);
            httpWebRequestContent.Method = "POST";

            using (StreamWriter streamWriterContent = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequestContent.GetRequestStream(),Encoding.UTF8))
            {

                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    message = Message,
                    sender = Sender,
                    etkFlag = false,
                    receivers = Receivers
                });
                streamWriterContent.Write(json);
            }

            HttpWebResponse httpResponseContent = null;
            httpResponseContent = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequestContent.GetResponse();

            var response = new SendSMSResponseClass();
            using (StreamReader streamReaderContent = new StreamReader(httpResponseContent.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string message = streamReaderContent.ReadToEnd();
                response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SendSMSResponseClass>(message);
            }

            return response;
```

This is the code that I post REST API method.

The problem is they want me to use charset:UTF-8 if I use \ in my message. However when I run this code , it doesn't do what I want to do with '\n' in the result.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this: "However when I run this code , it doesn't do what I want to do with '\n' in the result." Please take some time to be *really, really* clear about what's in your JSON, what you expected to be in the request, and what you're actually seeing. (It's unclear where UTF-8 comes in here, too...)

Comment: (As an aside, I'd strongly recommend migrating to HttpClient as well.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Im trying to send a sms in this codeblock. I have \r\n in my message property to jump down in my sms. However the result clear my \r\n and it doesnt jump. That is the problem.

Comment: for example: this is my message: turkcell test\r\n\r\nmesajussu. But when I run it and get the sms its like turkcell mesajussu

Comment: Please *edit the question* to include all the relevant information rather than adding comments. (Your question doesn't even *mention* SMS! It's entirely possible that the SMS provider doesn't support line breaks, for example. Nothing to do with UTF-8 at all.)